# How to change log retention policy in elk stack?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elk stack to retain and monitor the nginx-ingress logs of my k8s cluster. Instead of kibana Im using Grafana and instead of fluentd Im using fuent-bit. I found one documentation saying elasticsearch retain logs for 7 days and I also found an article where it said it retains logs life long.

All I want is the logs for last 6 months and any logs beyond that is not needed.

I have checked values.yaml file of elasticsearch to see if I can find the configuration option to change logs retention time but to no avail.

Has anyone worked with similar stack and knows how to change logs retention time???
Your time will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retaining data, You need to configure [Index Lifecycle Policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html#ilm-policy-definition). Currently, if you have not configured ILM policy, then Elastic will retain log data for a lifetime and it will not automatically deleted. You can create policy from Kibana as well but as you are mentioning you are not using Kibana, you can follow below command.

> To create a lifecycle policy from Kibana, open the menu and go to
> **Stack Management > Index Lifecycle Policies**. Click **Create policy**.

You can configured ILM Policy using below API:

```json
PUT _ilm/policy/my_policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "7d"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "30d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {} 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above policy will rolls the index over if it was created at least 7 days ago and     Delete the index 30 days after rollover.

You can assign created policy to your index using below command:

```json
PUT logs-my_app-default/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "my_policy"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

You can use [Explain lifecycle API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-explain-lifecycle.html) to validate if ILM is working properly or not.

```json
GET my-index-000001/_ilm/explain
```

Comment: thank you so much @Sagar Patel for the time and your detailed answer. For the test I have setup kibana as well so I could do it frm UI and Dev tool it provides.. 

With this how can I verify that the logs are using the custom policy I made? And since Im planning to not use a UI here, Where/How would I use the API (all I have as a configuration file is the helm charts)?

Comment: glad it helps you !!! for testing, you can configure `min_age` for delete to 1 or 2 days and validate it. For checking, if ILM is working or not you can use explain lifecycle api. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Is this then any different from monitoring indices created automatically by Metricsbeat? E.g. expecting indices like e.g. ` .ds-.monitoring-es-8-mb-2023.11.05-000188` to be deleted with policy `_ilm/policy/.monitoring-8-ilm-policy` and similar JSON as in your sample, but they're not

Comment: @Lyn .ds index means it is data stream index which is newly added concept in elastic version. for that there should be ilm policy available.

Comment: @SagarPatel indeed, there's the ILM policy `.monitoring-8-ilm-policy` with `"max_age": "3d"` and `"min_age": "3d"` for deletion, however, those indices are never deleted.

Comment: @Lyn I will say please raise new question and put your configuration so will be able to help.